# angular test which returns function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have written below test case but it does not cover this line :  () => service.getUserProfile()

```
export function userServiceFactory(service: UserService) {
  return () => service.getUserProfile();
}
```

test:

```
 import * as userserv from './user.service';
  it('should call userServiceFactory function', () => {
    const spy = spyOn(userService, 'getUserProfile').and.callThrough();
    userService.getUserProfile();
    const result = userserv.userServiceFactory(userService);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(result).toBeDefined();
  });
```

Comment: `userServiceFactory` doesn't call `userService.getUserProfile`, it returns a function that would do so when invoked. Your test only passes because you already called that spied method directly, which isn't a good idea - you can remove the call to `userServiceFactory` entirely and still see `expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()` being met...

Comment: Could you please guide how to write testcase to cover all lines?

Comment: I'd suggest you *call the function your function returns*. Or revisit what it returns, but we can't tell you whether or not your current implementation is actually correct.

Comment: Do you mean this? it('should call userServiceFactory function', () => {
  Const result=userService.getUserProfile() ;
    expect(result).toBeDefined();
  });

Comment: That would be directly calling the spy which, again, is not a good idea. The point of a spy is for *the code under test* to call it, calling them from the test code is a sign you're doing the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
it('should call userServiceFactory and invoke getUserProfile ', () => {
  const getUserProfileSpy = spyOn(userService, 'getUserProfile') ;
  const result = userserv.userServiceFactory(userService);
  result.call(userService.getUserProfile);
  expect(getUserProfileSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```